# Does a basis $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x,y,z)=(x-y,y-z,x-z)$ be a linear map. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$, such that the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $\cal H$ is:
> $$M(f,\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H})=\left( \begin{matrix}
> 2 & -2 & -2 \\
> -2 & 2 & 2\\
> 2 & -2 & -2
> \end{matrix}\right)$$
> Is it possible for such basis $\mathcal H$ to exist?

I confess I'm a little stuck in this problem. I see no reason for it not to exist but I can't prove that it exists. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of $f$ in the standard basis $\mathcal{B} = \{[1, 0, 0]^T, [0, 1, 0]^T, [0, 0, 1]^T\}$ is

$$
M(f,\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B})=\left( \begin{matrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Compute the trace of $\mathrm{tr}M(f,\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}) = 1 + 1 - 1 = 1$. However,  trace is basis-independent, so your matrix cannot be a matrix of $f$ in any basis.

Answer (score 1):

First, let $\cal B$ denote the standard basis. With respect to this basis, we note that we have

$$A := M(f, \cal B, \cal B) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that $A$ has trace $1$. However, the matrix in your question has $2$. Since trace is invariant under similarity and change of basis gives similar matrices, we see that the given matrix is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The trace of a linear map with respect to a basis does not depend upon the basis.